# How to include additional dependencies when packaging an sbt app using sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to include the breeze-natives dependency only when packaging the app (`universal:packageBin` and `debian:packageBin`) while always including the breeze dependency. Here is what I came up with :

```
val breezeDependencySettings = {
  val breezeUniversalNativesDependency =  libraryDependencies in Universal += D.breezeNatives
  val breezeDebianNativesDependency =  libraryDependencies in Debian += D.breezeNatives
  val breezeDependency = libraryDependencies += D.breeze
  Seq(breezeUniversalNativesDependency, breezeDebianNativesDependency, breezeDependency)
}
```

And in the project that I want to package, I use

```
settings =  (mySettings) ++ SbtNativePackager.packageArchetype.java_server ++
    Dependencies.breezeDependencySettings
```

However, the breeze-natives dependency is not included in the final package created by `universal:packageBin`. (breeze is included correctly though)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on your requirement but have you tried ExportJars := true?

See the excerpt from my build in my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035100/how-to-remove-version-from-artifactid-generated-by-sbt-native-packager

Comment: My requirement is basically that I do not want breeze-natives in my classpath most of the time, but I want it to be present when I package the app using sbt-native-packager.

Comment: I have also tried exprtJars := true, and it did not change anything.